# Oracle data pump: export - import

Tags: database, oracle

We're migrating our database from `WE8MSWIN1252` to `AL32UTF8`, the data is converted automatically to utf8, some times we get an error `ORA-12899`: `value too large for column xxx`, which is normal since non latin chars are encoded in more than one byte.
We want to achieve this in the same export data and data structure, then we import only the data structure, then execute a Sql script to modify the columns charset : `varchar2(4000 byte)` becomes `varchar2(4000 char)` and finally we export the data.
Could you please say me if this is possible in one export and one import ?
Thank you in advance for your help,

Bilel

Comment: Note, even if you declare `varchar2(4000 char)` then the real limit is still 4000 **Byte** (unless you use parameter `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED`)

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit this will be done in my SQL script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be import three steps:

1. expdp with `CONTENT=ALL` (which is the default)
2. impdp with `CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY`
3. your sql script to modify column types
4. impdp with `CONTENT=DATA_ONLY`

Comment: Thank you :) this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: please note that I need to disable constraints before importing the data and enable them after the end of the import

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only one export and import by adding to `impdp`

```
sqlfile=<schema_creation_script>.sql
```

This will use the script to create the tables instead of information which is in to the dump file

Comment: the sqlfile: <schema_creation_script>.sql  will executed after the data structure import and before the data import ?

Comment: As far as I know no, the script will be used to create the schema before start of import. And exported meta data will not be used to create tables, etc

Comment: ok, thank you, this means that I've to do it 3 steps : export and import data structure, excute my script,export and import  data ?

Comment: @BilelChaouadi, the steps are: 1. Prepare sql script. 2. export. 3. import the dump with sql script as I describe in answer

Comment: I don't want extract the SQL, what I want do is to import only the data structrue from the a full import, then execute my sql, then import the data (data only without strcture)

Comment: @BilelChaouadi, it's up to you. I offer you most flexible way.